# Dynamicly generated html not firing onclick event

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

This is my C# building the html. I tried to change the OnServerClick with the onclick and onclientclick with the result that:

- Onserverclick does not fire anything
- onclick gives me an exception
  that tells me that the method is not defined
- onclientclick does not
  fire nothing

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/img/"));
        List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();

        tabellaDownload.InnerHtml += "<table>";
        foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
        {
           files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
           // tabellaDownload.InnerHtml += "<tr><td  OnServerClick = 'DownloadFile' runat='server'>" + Path.GetFileName(filePath) + "<td></tr>";
           tabellaDownload.InnerHtml += "<input type='button' runat='server' OnServerClick='DownloadFile' value='asd' />";    
        }

        tabellaDownload.InnerHtml += "</table>";
        string asd = "";
    }
}             

protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Hi, here you are rendering a button with runat=server attribute, this wont run at server. You should check how runat=server (webforms controls) work.

Comment: even if i remove runat= server it doesn't work

Comment: when you send a string into an InnerHtml attribute you are sending what you want to display in the browser! to make the question simpler the browser doesn't know any OnServerClick directives! Only the asp.net engine knows it! check my answer edited!;)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do is to add a control to your form so if you want to do it dynamically you need to do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlButton b = new HtmlButton
    b.ServerClick += MyEvent;
    tabellaDownload.Controls.Add(b);
    /* a table control doesn't accept a btn as child, you need to the exact td cell where insert the button*/
}

protected void MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Everything in web form is a control included in a controls collection.

The Aspx files contains in forms of mark-up a mix of html and server directives(you can notice the difference by the runat attribute which marks the server directives), the server side directives are rendered as html mark-up to send to the browser, in a way similar to this:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$ctl00" onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$ctl00','')" type="button">
```

When you assign a string to InnerHtml attribute of a control, you are sending exactly what you want to render client side but there is no one html specific(or ecma script specific) that defines the runat attribute!

Comment: i don't want to add system.web.ui  buttons and other elements, i want to do the same thing i do when i add 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="REGISTER" class="bt_login field" runat="server" onserverclick="RegisterButton_Click"> from an aspx page (which is perfectly working

Comment: @Lorenzo so you can try this:  HtmlButton b = new HtmlButton();
            b.ServerClick += MyEvent; and then add to the controls of tabelladownload. You can't point to a server element from an html string. When you do that in the aspx file you are creating server directives that will be rendered as html string. So is just an illusion that in aspx works what you are trying to do!